# Chessboard - HTML(5) only

Tags: html, chess

I'm new in HTML and I came to the exercise, where I have to make chess board in HTML only. I searched a lot on the google and I found many solutions with Canvas and CSS, but I want to do it with HTML and then write the names of the rows and columns (on the sides).
Can you give me few suggestions how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: A 9x9 table perhaps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a table element.

Each square is represented with a td element. Each row and column element is represented with a th.

In the example I also added CSS to style the chess board.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .chess-board { border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
            .chess-board th { padding: .5em; }
            .chess-board td { border: 1px solid; width: 2em; height: 2em; }
            .chess-board .light { background: #eee; }
            .chess-board .dark { background: #000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="chess-board">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                    <th>d</th>
                    <th>e</th>
                    <th>f</th>
                    <th>g</th>
                    <th>h</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: chess board]

(ADDED)

If you want to add the pieces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .chess-board { border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
            .chess-board th { padding: .5em; }
            .chess-board th + th { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
            .chess-board th:first-child,
            .chess-board td:last-child { border-right: 1px solid #000; }
            .chess-board tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 1px solid; }
            .chess-board th:empty { border: none; }
            .chess-board td { width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em; text-align: center; font-size: 32px; line-height: 0;}
            .chess-board .light { background: #eee; }
            .chess-board .dark { background: #aaa; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="chess-board">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                    <th>d</th>
                    <th>e</th>
                    <th>f</th>
                    <th>g</th>
                    <th>h</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <td class="light">♜</td>
                    <td class="dark">♞</td>
                    <td class="light">♝</td>
                    <td class="dark">♛</td>
                    <td class="light">♚</td>
                    <td class="dark">♝</td>
                    <td class="light">♞</td>
                    <td class="dark">♜</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <td class="dark">♖</td>
                    <td class="light">♘</td>
                    <td class="dark">♗</td>
                    <td class="light">♕</td>
                    <td class="dark">♔</td>
                    <td class="light">♗</td>
                    <td class="dark">♘</td>
                    <td class="light">♖</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: chess board with the pieces]

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>&#9632;</td>
                <td>&#9633;</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

a
                b
                c
                d
                e
                f
                g
                h
                
            
            
                8
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                8
            
            
                7
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                7
            
            
                6
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                6
            
            
                5
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                5
            
            
                4
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                4
            
            
                3
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                3
            
            
                2
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                2
            
            
                1
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                ■
                □
                1
            
              
                
                a
                b
                c
                d
                e
                f
                g
                h

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
<div class="chessboard">
    <div>
        <div></div><div>a</div><div>b</div><div>c</div><div>d</div><div>e</div><div>f</div><div>g</div><div>h</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>8</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>7</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>6</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>5</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>3</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>2</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>1</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with `css` style:

```
.chessboard{
 width: 450px; height:450px;
  border-style:solid; 
 font-size:20px; line-height:2.5; 
 text-align:center;}

.chessboard>div{height:11.11%;}

.chessboard>div>div{
 width:11.11%; height:100%;
 display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}

.chessboard>div:nth-child(odd)>div:nth-child(even),
.chessboard>div:nth-child(even)>div:nth-child(odd)
 {background-color:black; color:white;}

.chessboard>div:nth-child(1),.chessboard>div>div:nth-child(1)
 {background-color:black; color:white; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could fill a div with 81 square divs, all floated left.

Check out the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/scdwypfg/3/).

CSS:

```
.board{
    border: 10px solid red;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
}
.tile{
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.tile:nth-child(even){
    background-color: black;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="board">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <!-- and so on... -->  


</div>
```

Comment: you're using css, he said no css :)

Comment: Ack! You're right. Oh well.